# Date in CRU data is starting from 380 instead of 1, since unit is days since 1900-1-1

Tags: raster, r, climate

I ran the following line of command. Below result show that:

> " time  Size:1380   *** is unlimited ***
> long_name: time
> units: days since 1900-1-1
> calendar: gregorian

```
 daily_rain <- "cru_ts4.00.1901.2015.pre.dat" #file name
> ncfname <- paste(daily_rain, ".nc", sep = "")
> dname <- "daily_rain"
> ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
> print(ncin)
```

File cru_ts4.00.1901.2015.pre.dat.nc (NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC):

```
 2 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    float pre[lon,lat,time]   
        long_name: precipitation
        units: mm/month
        correlation_decay_distance: 450
        _FillValue: 9.96920996838687e+36
        missing_value: 9.96920996838687e+36
    int stn[lon,lat,time]   
        description: number of stations contributing to each datum

 3 dimensions:
    lon  Size:720 
        long_name: longitude
        units: degrees_east
    lat  Size:360 
        long_name: latitude
        units: degrees_north
    time  Size:1380   *** is unlimited *** 
        long_name: time
        units: days since 1900-1-1
        calendar: gregorian

8 global attributes:
    Conventions: CF-1.4
    title: CRU TS4.00 Precipitation
    institution: Data held at British Atmospheric Data Centre, RAL, UK.
    source: Run ID = 1701270849. Data generated from:pre.1701161043.dtb
    history: Fri 27 Jan 2017 13:03:51 GMT : User ianharris : Program makegridsauto.for called by update.for
    references: Information on the data is available at http://badc.nerc.ac.uk/data/cru/
    comment: Access to these data is available to any registered CEDA user.
    contact: BADC <badc@rl.ac.uk>
```

However when I generate the time variable and call for head it starts with 380, which ideally should have started with 1.

```
#Reading the time variable
> t <- ncvar_get(ncin, "time")
> tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin, "time", "units")
> nt <- dim(t)
> head(t)
```

> [1] 380 410 439 470 500 531
> min(t) [1] 380

Why is that and is it right?

Comment: Can you link to the data file source? Saves us searching round the CRU site for the exact file.

Answer (score 0):

The data is 1901-2015, and as stated in the units:

```
> tunits
$hasatt
[1] TRUE

$value
[1] "days since 1900-1-1"
```

... the origin is 1900-01-01, hence the dates are:

```
> as.Date(380, origin="1900-01-01")
[1] "1901-01-16"
```

Which is the middle of January 1901.

The dates look like the middle of the month from 1901 to 2015, as advertised:

```
> as.Date(sort(t), origin="1900-01-01")
   [1] "1901-01-16" "1901-02-15" "1901-03-16" "1901-04-16" "1901-05-16"
   [6] "1901-06-16" "1901-07-16" "1901-08-16" "1901-09-16" "1901-10-16"
  [11] "1901-11-16" "1901-12-16" "1902-01-16" "1902-02-15" "1902-03-16"
[etc]
[1366] "2014-10-16" "2014-11-16" "2014-12-16" "2015-01-16" "2015-02-15"
[1371] "2015-03-16" "2015-04-16" "2015-05-16" "2015-06-16" "2015-07-16"
[1376] "2015-08-16" "2015-09-16" "2015-10-16" "2015-11-16" "2015-12-16"
```

This is assuming I've got the same data file as you. I don't see any messages like `" time Size:1380 *** is unlimited *** long_name: time units: days since 1900-1-1 calendar: gregorian"` as you say in the question, but the time values and unit specification seem reasonable.